# logcat '*:W' -d -f /mycache/log.txt outputs Info and Debug lines

Tags: android

Inside Android (not on adb), we need `logcat '*:W' -d -f /mycache/log.txt` to obey the `*:W` and only put Warning and Error lines into `log.txt`.

But -f appears to not obey the :W, and we get all the excess lines in the log.

Variations with > don't work thru `.exec()`, and I don't want to collect the output as a stream when the low-level command should obey me.

Comment: May be useful: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/logging/+/refs/tags/android-12.1.0_r2/logcat/logcat.cpp

Answer (score 0):

take out the '':

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat *:W -d -f " + logFile.getAbsoluteFile());
```

It turns out `.exec()` calls the raw process loader, not a command shell, so it wouldn't have expanded the *, so the '' aren't needed or expected.

(I posted because I thought I already tried that;)